# Why is pageant putty authentication agent running on my laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a new Windows 10 laptop. I just saw three instances of "pageant putty authentication agent" in my task bar inside one "box"/widget. When I opened the box, only one instance remained.

I did not install putty or pagent. So, why is this running on my system ? If it need not run, then how do I disable it ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you did not install putty or any program that ships with Putty (e.g. TortoiseGIT) it looks like the laptop was not new.

Comment: @Robert - I had reinstalled the OS recently. But, I also installed source tree and git kraken, besides other developer tools. I now wonder to to find out which app installed pagent.

Answer (score 2):

Noticed this on my laptop too recently and saw it's under Source Tree.

Very late, but just in case someone else runs into this too.